# How to split dataframes of a list then join them based on a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, list, split, bind

I have scattered data sets with different observations from different years in a list
I want to group observations from the same years in the same datasets.

```
mydata1<-data.frame(ID=1:5, year=c(2011:2015),Weight=c(50:54))
mydata2<-data.frame(ID=6:10, year=c(2011:2013,2011,2014),Weight=c(52:56))
mydata3<-data.frame(ID=11:15, year=c(2011:2013,2011,2015),Weight=c(61:65))
mydata4<-data.frame(ID=16:20, year=c(2012:2014,2015,2013),Weight=c(70:74))

mydatalist<-list(mydata1=mydata1,
     mydata2=mydata2,
     mydata3=mydata3,
     mydata4=mydata4)
```

Normally, the code below allows me to do this, but that's not what I want. If I understand this method correctly, all the datasets are bound first, then split by year.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(mydatalist) %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$year))
```

But I don't have enough space in my computer memory to join all my actual datasets

What I want to do is first split all the datasets by year, then join them back together.

I want something that does this internally:

```
$[[1]]
  ID year Weight
1  1 2011     50

$[[2]]
  ID year Weight
1  2 2012     51

$[[3]]
  ID year Weight
1  3 2013     52

$[[4]]
  ID year Weight
1  4 2014     53

$[[5]]
  ID year Weight
5  5 2015     54

$[[6]]
  ID year Weight
1  6 2011     52
2  9 2011     55

$[[7]]
  ID year Weight
1  7 2012     53

$[[8]]
  ID year Weight
1  8 2013     54

$[[9]]
  ID year Weight
1 10 2014     56

......... etc
```

before getting this format:

```
$`2011`
   ID year Weight
1   1 2011     50
6   6 2011     52
9   9 2011     55
11 11 2011     61
14 14 2011     64

$`2012`
   ID year Weight
2   2 2012     51
7   7 2012     53
12 12 2012     62
16 16 2012     70

$`2013`
   ID year Weight
3   3 2013     52
8   8 2013     54
13 13 2013     63
17 17 2013     71
20 20 2013     74

$`2014`
   ID year Weight
4   4 2014     53
10 10 2014     56
18 18 2014     72

$`2015`
   ID year Weight
5   5 2015     54
15 15 2015     65
19 19 2015     73
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `purrr`:

If you want to do this in intermediate steps, you can just assign parts of the chained `(%>%)` operations to a variable, e.g.:

```r
step1 <- mydatalist %>% 
  map(~split(.x, .x$year)) 

step2 <- step1 %>% 
  list_flatten(name_spec = "{inner}") %>% 
  list_rbind() %>% 
  split(.$year)
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

mydata1<-data.frame(ID=1:5, year=c(2011:2015),Weight=c(50:54))
mydata2<-data.frame(ID=6:10, year=c(2011:2013,2011,2014),Weight=c(52:56))
mydata3<-data.frame(ID=11:15, year=c(2011:2013,2011,2015),Weight=c(61:65))
mydata4<-data.frame(ID=16:20, year=c(2012:2014,2015,2013),Weight=c(70:74))

mydatalist<-list(mydata1=mydata1,
                 mydata2=mydata2,
                 mydata3=mydata3,
                 mydata4=mydata4)



mydatalist %>% 
  map(~split(.x, .x$year)) %>% 
  list_flatten(name_spec = "{inner}") %>% 
  list_rbind() %>% 
  split(.$year)

#> $`2011`
#>    ID year Weight
#> 1   1 2011     50
#> 6   6 2011     52
#> 7   9 2011     55
#> 11 11 2011     61
#> 12 14 2011     64
#> 
#> $`2012`
#>    ID year Weight
#> 2   2 2012     51
#> 8   7 2012     53
#> 13 12 2012     62
#> 16 16 2012     70
#> 
#> $`2013`
#>    ID year Weight
#> 3   3 2013     52
#> 9   8 2013     54
#> 14 13 2013     63
#> 17 17 2013     71
#> 18 20 2013     74
#> 
#> $`2014`
#>    ID year Weight
#> 4   4 2014     53
#> 10 10 2014     56
#> 19 18 2014     72
#> 
#> $`2015`
#>    ID year Weight
#> 5   5 2015     54
#> 15 15 2015     65
#> 20 19 2015     73
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Matt the functions list_rbind an list_flatten that seem to depend on purrr ar not working. May be it is because of the version of purrr. I try to reinstall purrr

Comment: Yeah, those are newer `purrr` functions. If you run `install.packages('purrr')` and restart your session, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most optimal solution, but I would suggest outputting the data in small chunks, then read them back in.

First, we need to figure out how many unique years there are in total.

```
AllYears <- c()

for(i in 1:length(mydatalist)){
  
  AllYears <- unique(c(AllYears, mydatalist[[i]][, "year"]))
  
}
```

We can then run a loop to output all those tables, divided by the years. E.g., there will be 5 output for mydata1, 1 output for each year. It is important that the names of the output tables indicate the year, so they can be easily identified later on.

```
for(i in 1:length(AllYears)){
  
  for(j in 1:length(mydatalist)){
    
    TempDF <- mydatalist[[j]][mydatalist[[j]][, "year"] == AllYears[i], ]
    
    if(nrow(TempDF) > 0){
      save(TempDF,
           file = paste0("Small Files/", names(mydatalist)[j], "_",
                         AllYears[i], ".RDS"))
      
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I can list the small output chunks and read them in one by one, according to the year.

```
AllYearFiles <- list.files("Small Files/", full.names = T)

FinalList <- list()

for(i in 1:length(AllYears)){
  
  TempFiles <- AllYearFiles[grepl(AllYears[i], AllYearFiles)]
  FinalList[[i]] <- data.frame()
  
  for(j in 1:length(TempFiles)){
    
    load(TempFiles[j])
    FinalList[[i]] <- rbind(FinalList[[i]], TempDF)
    rm(TempDF)
    
  }
  
}

names(FinalList) <- AllYears
```

Comment: I agree that what you propose is most optimal. But I do want to create a lot of intermediate files. And also want to create most succint code. It is a trade-off that suits me